# Flex LinkButton selectable

Tags: apache-flex, flash, copy-paste

Is it possible to make a `LinkButton` selectable? That is, the text from the LinkButton can be selected and then copied. LinkButton does not have the `selectable` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to create your own `LinkButton` by extending a `Text` control. Just style it to look like the `LinkButton` (blue, underlined) and set the following properties:

```
buttonMode = true;
useHandCursor = true;
```

Then just handle the MouseEvent.CLICK event as you would with any `Button`.